# cannot acquire data source trying to Unit test java persistence Entity Manager

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, datasource

I am fairly new to JPA and I wanted to test my EntityManagers persistance/deletion etc. I keep recieving an error that i cannot accquire 
data source . I am at a complete lose, I have searched online for hours and cannot find(or at least understand) any answers on the web. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

**This is the test class.**

```
@Transactional
public class DoctorRepositoryTest
{
   private DoctorRepository dr;
   private Doctor doctor;
   private EntityManagerFactory emf
       = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("TestPersistence");
  private  EntityManager em = null;


public DoctorRepositoryTest()
{
}

@BeforeClass
public static void setUpClass()
{

}

@AfterClass
public static void tearDownClass()
{
}

@Before
public void setUp()
{




  dr = new DoctorRepository();

  doctor = new Doctor(0,"doctorFirstName", "doctorLastName", "4032223333", 
  "123 45 ave NW","Calgary", "AB", "t3k5c9");


}

@After
public void tearDown()
{
   dr = null;
   doctor = null;
}

/**
 * Testings method for the insertion of Doctor Objects to
 * the database
 */
@Test
public void testInsert(){



    int result;
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
     try
   {
      em.getTransaction().begin();
      em.persist(doctor);
      em.getTransaction().commit();
      result = 1;
   }
     catch(Exception e){

        result = 0;
     }
   finally
   {
      em.close();
   }

     assertEquals(result,1);

}
```

**This is my persistence xml**

```
    <persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence   http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="SunrisePU" transaction-type="JTA">
   <jta-data-source>SunriseDB</jta-data-source>
   <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties/>
  </persistence-unit>
  <persistence-unit name="TestPersistence" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <jta-data-source>SunriseDB</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**The Error I keep getting is.**

```
[EL Info]: 2016-03-27 12:50:44.151--ServerSession(957465255)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd

[EL Severe]: ejb: 2016-03-27 12:50:48.588--ServerSession(957465255)--Exception     
[EclipseLink-7060] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
```

Exception Description: Cannot acquire data source [SunriseDB].

There is much more to the error, but the root cause is that i cannot connect to my database for the testing.

Comment: Because you are using spring this link may be helpful http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html

Comment: if the root cause of the error is that you cannot connect to your database, then that's the problem you should be investigating.  Figure out what's wrong with your DB/Server config and why you're not able to connect to it.  The snippets you posted are irrelevant if your DB configuration is incorrect.

Comment: well when I run my project, it connects to the database just fine, im not sure what to do :/. I tried adding things to the property section which was suggested below, by that didn't help either unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem is that you don't have nothing in the properties section in the persistence.xml file...

```
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/prytest"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    </properties>
```

Check the correct configuration to the driver depending of your DBMS (in my case is MySql)

Comment: i added preoperties matching my own project, but cannot access the datasource still. No matter what  I do.......My regular project runs just fine :/. Database access is quick and easy. I am at a complete loss